# ASP.Net MVC 3 what folders are web visible

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have some sensitive files that I want the web server to be able to use, but I do not want them to be accessible from a web browser.

I am having a really hard time finding any documentation that describes which folders in ASP.Net are hosted publicity and which are private. For instance I know the Content and Scripts directory are public, but I see no configuration or options that show granting access to those paths.

What folders are web accessible? And where would it be safe to put these sensitive files?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> have some sensitive files that I want the web server to be able to
>   use, but I do not want them to be accessible from a web browser.

`~/App_Data` is for you. Here's a list of the different [ASP.NET special folders](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ex526337.aspx).

Comment: Is there any documentation on what other folders are shard by default? Or some configuration file that specifies what files are shared?

Comment: @metalideath, I doubt it. There is documentation about the ASP.NET special folders and what their role is: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ex526337.aspx

Comment: Yeah I come from more of a Java background. I am finding the quality and quantity of documentation on ASP.Net and C# to be pretty poor as compared to their Java counterparts. I am really surprised by this, I would have expected Microsoft to have much better documentation.

Comment: You could run into trouble if you're using App_Data and Web Deployment, as your project's deployment may exclude files in the App_Data directory by default. Check the Package/Publish Web section of the web project's Properties if this happens.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about which special folders are locked down (other than App_Data & bin), but you can block any folder from being web accessible by adding an `<authorization/>` section to a `<location/>` section to your web.config:

```
<!-- Block access to Admin directory -->
<location path="Admin">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <deny users="*" />
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

Alternatively, you can add a web.config directly to the directory you want to block, containing the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- This web.config blocks access to any directory it is put in, 
     and its subdirectories -->
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <deny users="*" />
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

These approaches are functionally identical, it just depends on your preference. Personally, I think having the web.config file in the directory you're blocking access to is a little less confusing.

Comment: I really like the piece of mind that would give me. I am starting to think ASP.Net shares all folders except those two you mentioned. And it just blocks certain extensions like .cs globally by default.

Comment: I'm not sure if there's documentation on which extensions are blocked, but you can find them in the root web config, which is stored in C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\{version}\Config\web.config (where {version} is the version of .NET the web uses.)

Look for rules like `<add path="*.cs" verb="*" type="System.Web.HttpForbiddenHandler" validate="True" />`